# Convert string with delimiter to an array in Json using AWK

Tags: arrays, json, awk, gawk

I have below style format json and I would like to convert the values in double quotes with delimiter comma to array of elements.

The json field I would like to convert is a part of huge Json file.

So I need to find the field

**Convert**

```
Before
{"name": "john, jane, gordon, matthew"} 

               to 
After    
{"field": ["john","jane","gordon", "matthew"]}
```

Comment: Unless your Json file has entries in a single line, you'll have a hard time doing it with AWK. Does it have to be AWK?

Comment: No not really. It can be any language. Also whole json is in single line. I saw your code. How will it identify the field name

Comment: I did not understand what you want to do with `name`.

Comment: because there are so many fields. We find "name" fields for each json object. Here, (name)key-value(comma delimiter values). We separate each value and add format it to an array.

Comment: If you observe above json sample, You will see that I separate john, jane, gordon, matthew. which is currently a single value to array of values.

Answer (score 1):

If your Json file has entries in a single line, then this AWK program works for your example:

```
{
    sub(": *",": [")
    sub("}","]}")
    gsub(", *","\",\"")
    print
}
```

If your data is in a single line, replace `sub` with `gsub`.

Comment: It didnt work, gave a real format. whole object in [] and few are separated, etc.. I cant figure out what happened. I think we need to find "field": and then do the operation on it. I dont know awk much.

Comment: You don't need to know awk much to ask a question, you just need to provide sample input/output that's truly representative of your real data. If the sample in your question does not truly represent your real data than change it so it does.

Answer (score 0):

If all the lines have similar format , try out this

```
 awk '{print gensub(/\"/,"[","3")}' | awk '{print gensub(/\"}$/,"]}","")}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I think sed is also good like in this case

```
$ sed -r 's/"([^"]+)".*"([^"]+)"/{"\1": ["\2"]}/; s/ ?, ?/","/g' file
{{"name": ["john","jane","gordon","matthew"]}}
```